# Reset outlook to auto selects

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

when sending email from outlook it populates a list of suggestions.  We moved email servers recently so some of the addresses are no longer valid.  How can I have the "suggestions" cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to the autocomplete function of the `TO:` field in Outlook, that data is kept locally on a per user and per profile basis.

Typically it is found in a User's directory as an NK2 file. By defaults it is usually named outlook.nk2. This file is profile specific (Outlook profile) and contains all previously used sent addresses.

If you delete the file, the next time Outlook is started a new one will be created and will begin collecting sent addresses again.

On XP it is found in C:\Documents and Settings\UserID\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook
On Win7 it is found in C:\Users\UserID\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook

You can also selectively remove items from the autocomplete by beginning to type a name you want to remove in the `TO:` field and when it displays, arrow over it with the keyboard and press the "Delete" key.